# SmtpClient.Send with VALID email address that has a comma in it

Tags: c#, email, smtp

SmtpClient.Send(...) is OK with simple email addresses (eg "JoeBlow@MyCo.com") or fancier addresses (eg "Joe Blow <JoeBlow@MyCo.com>").
But my company has its address book entries formatted like "Blow,Joe <JoeBlow@MyCo.com>". SmtpClient chokes on this because it assumes that the comma is dividing two separate addresses. Is there a way to tell Smtp that I am not using commas in this way? Or is the only option to reformat the company addresses? Don't tell me to just eliminate everything other than the actual address because this extra name info is very useful.

Comment: Would you mind adding a copy&paste-ready snippet that I could modify? That would really be nice to the answerers and avoid work. Also, it shows that you did your homework and know at least the basics. Thanks.

Comment: An email address cannot have commas unless inside double quotes but it is highly discoraged. Perhaps the problem is in how you read your company address book and how you prepare the MailAddress instance. As usual, questions that are related to _why my code doesn't work?_ need to be completed with a sample of the failing code

Comment: Steve, yes of course the actual email address cannot have commas in it, but as my example clearly showed, frequently email applications accept addresses of the form "Joe Blow <JoeBlow@MyCo.com>". Try it in GMail for instance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a string like `"\"Blow, Joe\" <JoeBlow@MyCo.com>"` so that the comma is within a quoted-string.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET the MailAddress object has both an actual address field and a display name field. The display name CAN have commas (even if this is not encouraged). Using this object with the constructor with 2 parameters allows these funny display names to be used.

Comment: Worked perfectly, used MailAddress(email, name) with MailMessage.To collection.